# Bernoulli trials with a stopping rule

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider an infinite sequences of Bernoulli experiment with a probability of success of $p$, and consider a real number $\alpha$. At each date $t$, the process stops whenever the ratio of successes to failures falls below the threshold $\alpha$, and continues otherwise. Call $\tau$ the (potentially infinite) stopping time of this problem.

I am interested in the limit properties of this problem when $p$ gets close to 1. In particular, I would like to know whether it is true that the process almost never stops when $p$ is large enough, i.e. that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{p \rightarrow 1}{\mathbb{P}(\tau=+\infty)}=1
\end{equation*}

It is clear that for each finite $t$, 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{p \rightarrow 1}{\mathbb{P}(\tau>t)}=1
\end{equation*}

but I don't know how to deal with the limit. Any hint would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think the inequation $P(|\frac kn -p|> \epsilon) < \frac {pq}{n \epsilon ^2}$ would be helpful here!! where n is the number of times the xperiment is performed, k is the number of times the event occurs, p is the probability of event in a single trial, $\epsilon$ is any number $\gt 0$

Comment: Thank you @Jasser, that is useful indeed. Any hints on how to proceed from now? Simply summing $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{P(\dfrac{k}{n}<\alpha)}$ and observing that $P(\dfrac{k}{n}<\alpha) \leq \dfrac{p(1-p)}{n(p-\alpha)^2}$ does not work since the series does not converge.

Comment: Well I can see that $\alpha $ is the ratio of success to failure but you have written $\frac kn < \alpha$ instead of $\frac {k}{n-k} < \alpha $ and then try transforming it in the inequality I mentioned in the previous comment.... I guess this would work but not sure

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion, you are right, it should be $\dfrac{k}{n-k}$. Regarding the summation, $P(\dfrac{k}{n-k}<\alpha)$ gives the probability of terminating the history after $n$ trials, this is why I was summing it over $n$ (not over $k$) since I want to know the probability with which the process stops in finite time.

Comment: By the way where have you encountered this problem?? that would be helpful if you mention the source or give a link...

Comment: I'm starting to study stochastic processes on my own and I just thought of this problem, I didn't see it anywhere.